# textcomp malfunction

Tags: symbols

If I understand the last latex update, you don't need to declare textcomp any more to be able to use its symbols. What I am finding is that some of those symbols produce an error under the updated latex. Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}[=2018/08/11]
\begin{document}
Use of {\textmu} to Minimize Worker{s\textquotesingle} Risk of Musculoskeletal Injury.
\end{document}
```

It works fine with the rollback command (third line). If I remove it, I get these errors in the log file:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 Use of {\textmu
                   } to Minimize Worker{s\textquotesingle} Risk of Musculosk...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 ...extmu} to Minimize Worker{s\textquotesingle
                                                  } Risk of Musculoskeletal ...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any guidance? If that a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: works fine for me. Please show your log-file.

Comment: works for me too, please show error messages from `!` to `?` in a code block so line endings are preserved. (line breaks are vital to understand TeX error messages). I  suspect that the error message you show is from using a latex release older than 2020-02-02

Comment: As a side note: I have no problem with this sample. However, there does seem to be a problem with `\textpertenthousand ` if I use the fourier package. The maintainer of the fourier package has been notified.

Comment: @HerbSchulz that is not a problem of the package but a bug (typo) in the latex kernel which will be resolved with tomorrows update: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/262

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the information. I assumed it was related to the changes in the kernel associated with textcomp.

Comment: I pasted in the errors from the log file above. Note that I am running TeX Live and that my installation is selective but up to date.

Comment: no show the complete log. We need to see your file versions.

Comment: @EihabAbdel-Rahman in particular the error suggests that you are using an older latex, it should start off: `entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02>
L3 programming layer <2020-02-02>` I suspect your banner will have a 2019 date/

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the problem: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.5.10)  7 FEB 2020 11:36
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"cv copy.tex"
(./cv copy.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` Thank you.